# how to bind more than one dropdownlist without refreshing?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



        bindbranches();
        bindbranches1();

}
public void bindbranches()
{
    DataTable dtbranch = new DataTable();
    dtbranch = objsupplyBAL.getbrnch();

    ddlbranch.DataSource = dtbranch;
    ddlbranch.DataBind();
    ddlbranch.Items.Add(new ListItem("--select--", "0"));
    ddlbranch.SelectedIndex = ddlbranch.Items.Count - 1;

}
public void bindbranches1()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = objsupplyBAL.getbrnch();

    ddlbranch1.DataSource = dt;
    ddlbranch1.DataBind();
    ddlbranch1.Items.Add(new ListItem("--select--", "0"));
    ddlbranch1.SelectedIndex = ddlbranch1.Items.Count - 1;

}
```

My dropdownlist's are not binding without refreshing.If i select one dropdownlist another one is refreshing. What i have to add extra to my code. Can any one tell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(!IsPostBack)
 {

    bindbranches();
    bindbranches1();
  }
}
```

if you add this...it's work properly ...first try this...

Answer (score 1):

The reason that is happening is you are running the code every time the page postsback, try the following to only populate the items once (on the initial page load) :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!this.IsPostBack) {
        bindbranches();
        bindbranches1();
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can also handle the `Page.Init` event to run this code, this will change the dropdowns when the page is first loaded and will keep the values throughout subsequent postbacks :

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    bindbranches();
    bindbranches1();
}
```

If you want the second dropdown to refresh only when the first item is selected, try the following solution :

```
protected void ddlbranch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    bindbranches1();
}
```

And bind `ddlbranch_SelectedIndexChanged` to the selected index changed event of your ddlbranch control. This will only run the code when the page is initially loaded and when the user selects an item from the ddlbranch dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set AutoPostBack Property of the drop down to true if you want to fill another drop down on change of one drop down so on change event will start executing

Loot @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.autopostback.aspx

Comment: Even you can use Cascading Dropdown.